# Share computing between two processors

Tags: sockets, mpi, raspberry-pi3, distributed-computing

I am working on a project in which I have two raspberry pis, I want to share  process load between them, I am very much comfortable with sockets and have implemented program in which one pi is the host and sends the process request to another pi the other pi acknowledges the request then waits till the host sends the data stream for processing completes the task and sends the response back.

Is this method efficient or do I have to shift to MPI based libraries? I am programming it in C and I have to send bulk data for processing to the second raspberry pi.
Thanks

Comment: From a performance point of view, MPI can efficiently use high speed interconnects and shared memory ... but your rpi3 only has a 100Mb network, and if you run one process per node, you do do not need to care about shared memory performance. So if sockets work for you, then this is good enough. MPI has a high level semantic, and it could be easier to use if you plan to run several processes per node and/or you plan to have more rpi3 in a near future. Based on your description, this is more a "nice to have" than a requirement.

Comment: Yes Sir, actually its a part of a software defined radio project, where I have to process samples at 30 MSPs (each sample is a 16bit integer), so currently I am using pi as a secondary processor. After that, I would switch to banana pi which has gigabit ethernet and higher processing power and the number of processes would also increase. So in that situation also should I shift to MPI or optimise using sockets?

Comment: How many nodes and how many processes per node do you plan to run ?

Comment: There would be only two nodes, one host other would be the client, but there would be approx 6 parallel processes in total which would have to be shared between the nodes. one of the nodes would dump the processed data to an external ADC (the required rate of samples is 30 MSPs). out of the 6, 4 processes are not in the direct chain of ADC transmission and does not require to process samples with the given sampling rate (eg signal alignment).

Comment: sockets can be good enough. keep in mind most MPI libraries will spin (instead of poll/sleep) when waiting for a message, and this could be something you want to avoid.

Comment: Does any library or method exist in c that triggers or generates an interrupt when receiving some data on the ethernet which can be used as a callback. I have read about libevent but it generates a new thread for the loop action. Is there any other way in which it does not create extra threads for this